# how to add contents of list box to field in table?

Tags: ms-access

I have a form which contains listbox which will contains links of attachment when ever user use the file dialog. Is there a way to have a field in the corresponding table to contain all the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a new table in the database that will contain the links because there are many links (potentially) for each row.

```
links (linkid, mainid, linkpath)
```

mainid is the id of the record that you want these links attached to.

Then in the rowsource property of the listbox put a selects only those links with a mainid of the current record.

In the OnCurrent event of the form you will need a

```
listbox1.requery
```

statement